# float 2 elements inside inline-block horizontal

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float `span` and `ul` next to each other but without fixed width it wont float to each other horizontal but instead act like float wasen´t applied and stack vertical. When i set fixed width and remove `display:inline-block` from `updates-documents-holder-inside` it will appear to act as intended in first place. http://jsfiddle.net/Jx3dv/ to show the problem.

```
<div class="updates-documents-holder">
        <div class="updates-documents-holder-inside">
            <span><div></div></span>
            <ul>
                <li>Flytt av sopor.doc</li>
                <li>5FSE 0000 000</li>
                <li>Har blivit uppdaterad</li>
                <li>2014-28-15</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Css

```
.updates-documents-holder{
float:left;
width:23.8em;
height:5em;
text-align:center;

}
.updates-documents-holder-inside{
display:inline-block;

}
.updates-documents-holder-inside > span{
display:block;
float:left;
background:green;
}
.updates-documents-holder-inside > span > div{
display:block;
 height:50px;
width:50px;

}
.updates-documents-holder-inside > ul{
display:block;
float:left;
text-align:left;
list-style:inside;
padding-left:1em;
background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aibrean/jSZyh/3/

Here's a fiddle. Mixing floats and block elements is the cause of the problem. They don't play nice together.

Updated CSS code:

```
.updates-documents-holder-inside > span{
display:inline-block;
background:green;
}
.updates-documents-holder-inside > span > div{
    display:inline-block;
 height:50px;
    width:50px;

}
.updates-documents-holder-inside > ul{
display:inline-block;
text-align:left;
padding-left:1.5em;
background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to apply any fixed width. Just remove `display:inline-block` from the container `div.updates-documents-holder-inside`,

So that both the elements have enough space to sit next to each other.
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jx3dv/3/)

Comment: They are stacking vertically now, not horizontal.

Comment: @Nicco because by mistake i didn't remove the property from that fiddle... you could've just tried that... ah, nvm.